# Network connection issues with Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, hyper-v

I have been using the Visual Studio Emulator for Android for a while now for testing Xamarin.Android applications, but lately I have run into a new issue that I wasn't seeing previously. Before, when launching the emulator, there would be a brief interruption to my PC's network connection and then it would come back online and both the emulator and my PC would have a network connection and internet access. Lately, however, when I launch an emulator, my PC loses its network connection while the emulator has a connection. If I repair my PC network connection, it restores connectivity for my PC but the emulator loses its connection.

It looks like I can only have one or the other connected to the internet at any given time but I know for a fact that this was not the case before. I have done some searching and tried various troubleshooting steps that I found online but nothing has fixed the issue.

I am on the latest version of the Visual Studio Emulator for Android as of today (2017-03-27) and I have tried the following steps:

1. Deleted all my existing emulators from within Visual Studio Emulator for Android
2. Repair the installation for Visual Studio Emulator for Android
3. Deleted all virtual switches from within the Hyper-V Manager
4. Ran XDECleanup.exe

At least one of my co-workers is experiencing this exact same behavior so I am sure that others out there are running into this problem as well.